# Are there rules to adjust prices?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, downtime

For every item in the game, mundane, alchemical, magical or otherwise, as well as services, there is a fixed gold price listed. This is necessary because the crafting rules in Pathfinder-1e rely on this listed item price.

But do items cost exactly the same wherever you buy them? I know that there are rules regarding what the maximum price of an item you can buy in a town / city is, but are there any written rules how prices should vary according to town size, area etc.?

Comment: I note that in reality, the fluctuations of prices depend on a million considerations of availability of both objects and source materials, transportation, whether objects acquire (or lose) alternate uses, what replacements are feasible, and many other factors.  Hard to generalize.

Comment: In Pathfinder's parent system, D&D v.3.5, the Eberron campaign setting considers it a minor setting feature that the reason you can buy equipment from the Player's Handbook and Dungeon Master's Guide at the listed prices amounts to, "continent-wide regulators exist in the form of House Cannith's Fabricators Guild, House Ghallanda's Hospitality Guild, et al., ensuring licensees create items with as-book stats and offer services for book prices." Not an answer in itself, but if anyone feels like remarking on that element, it's useful context. First mention in a *Dragonmarked* sidebar, I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, Pathfinder 1e assumes that each item has a universal standard market price, using a standardized gold-piece currency. Although this assumption may seem unrealistic, it makes the worldbuilding and number-crunching more manageable for the GM. However, there are exceptions that may affect item prices.

First, settlements vary by size and they have their own statistics, which affect the availability of items.  These stat blocks are often written in published Pathfinder adventures, although the actual rules for these statistics are covered in the *Gamemastery Guide*, in the "[Settlements](http://legacy.aonprd.com/gameMasteryGuide/settlements.html)" section. A settlement's population size, alignment, and other social factors are meant to limit market factors. These limit the maximum price for nonmagical items for sale, the maximum amount that merchants will pay to buy loot from adventurers, maximum number of magic items for sale, the maximum spell level for spellcasting services available.

In addition to numeric stats, settlements may have Qualities and Disadvantages, some of which may affect item prices. For example:

> The community is prejudiced against one or more races, which are listed in parentheses. *(Members of the unwelcome race or races must pay 150% of the normal price for goods and services and may face mockery, insult, or even violence)*

Note that these statistics only apply to item sales. In terms of the costs for crafting items, these settlement-specific stats do not affect its effective "base price". The [magic item creation](https://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRuleBook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) rules define this price as dependent on the item's properties, rather than depending on where it is sold.

> Magic supplies for items are always half of the base price in gp. For many items, the market price equals the base price. Armor, shields, weapons, and items with value independent of their magically enhanced properties add their item cost to the market price. The item cost does not influence the base price (which determines the cost of magic supplies), but it does increase the final market price.

As a trivial example, suppose a town's eccentric wizard sells their *amulet of the planes* (market price 120,000 gp) for a mere 2 copper; this does not affect the item's "base price", and does not mean that anyone can craft the same item by spending 1 cp worth of materials.

There are exceptions that may affect market prices for certain items, and may even affect the prices for crafting. There are no general rules for this, and instead these are specified in various published adventures. I found some examples in the *Ire of the Storm* adventure module: If the PCs assist a local blacksmith, he offers a 10% discount on future purchases as a reward. Or if a disaster hits the town and destroys some shops, all prices in town will be 50% higher than normal.

There are some character-specific abilities (such as the [Hedge Magician](https://aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Hedge%20Magician) and [Spark of Creation](https://aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spark%20of%20Creation) traits) to reduce an individual's crafting costs, but I could not find published examples for generalized mechanics that affect crafting costs in a given market or area. Instead the GM is free to invent something on their own. For example, maybe the adventurers find a magic anvil that reduces the crafting cost of magic weapons, or they meet an alchemical supply merchant whose materials reduce potion crafting costs. The GM has discretion here, and should keep in mind that crafting magic items increases the PCs' effective power, and allowing PCs to craft items for cheaper can potentially lead to balance issues over time.

Comment: "any published examples of mechanics that affect crafting costs" *coughs in [Spark of creation](https://aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spark%20of%20Creation) and [Hedge Magician](https://aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Hedge%20Magician).*

Comment: @willuwontu Thanks for pointing those out, I added them to the answer. I should have been more specific, since I was trying to think of published mechanics that any character could use to reduce crafting costs, not just characters with special traits.

Comment: Fair, I'm also going to toss the [Bargaining Rules](http://legacy.aonprd.com/ultimateCampaign/campaignSystems/bargaining.html) at you, figure it's better for you to expand your answer rather than make a post about a single subsystem that doesn't answer the whole question.